# Exact matching regex replace

Tags: regex

I need to replace `@TableName1` to `test` using Regex in the following string:

```
@TableName1, @TableName11
pk_@TableName1_1, @TableName1_12
@TableName2
```

to look like this:

```
test, @TableName11
pk_test_1, test_12
@TableName2
```

I tried to use `\B@TableName1\b` but when I do this the `pk_@TableName1_1` is not replaced.

What should I do in such scenario?

Comment: Try `(?<![^\W_])@TableName1\b` or `(?<![^\W_])@TableName1(?![^\W_])`

Comment: Second one works. Thanks!

Comment: Posted from my mobile, please let know if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use custom boundaries:

```
(?<![^\W_])@TableName1(?![^\W_])
```

The lookarounds work as word boundaries but exclude the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
@TableName1(?!\d)
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YOpvVU/1)